# How can I test my HTTPListener

Tags: .net, web-services, httplistener

I have an HTTPListener (VB.NET) that is working and I'm trying to copy it and make a few changes.  I naturally didn't leave myself good notes on how I was able to test this.

Here's how this is supposed to work:
I send a request to webservice A (external, out of our control).  They send me back Results to this listener.  I know what the XML that I get back should look like.

I've done step 1, passing along the address of my listener.  I should quickly get back the results to my listener.  It's a console app that displays when it's gotten something.  That hasn't happened yet, but I feel like that's secondary to my problem right now.  At this point all I've done in my copy is rename the listener Prefix and of course the project name, etc., but that's all.

I would like a way to test this without having to go through the Vendor.  So I guess my question is:  Is there a way I can pass the XML to my Listener through the browser?  When I just append something to the end of the the listener URI, the content is blank.

I'm pretty sure that's how I tested this the first time, but it doesn't seem to work for me now.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be AWESOME!.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the .asmx page of the web service and put in what I would send them, which triggered the call that I was expecting.